# How to list unattached AWS IoT certificates

Tags: aws-iot

Is there a way to list all the unattached certificates? I want to delete them?

`aws iot list-certificates` only show me the certificate status.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/index.html#cli-aws-iot
I could not find anything helpful.

`aws cli` will do.

I am thinking to have a lambda function that will delete unattached certs.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how you can get the list?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in **two steps**:

1. Get the ARNs of your certificates using [list-certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/list-certificates.html)
2. For each ARN, use [list-principal-things](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/list-principal-things.html) which will list any `things` that are associated with the given cert.